# Unable to connect through Cqlsh to some of the Cassandra nodes with protocol version v4

Tags: cassandra

I have been seeing an issue with cqlsh not connecting to protocol version v4 on few nodes of a cassandra cluster. 20% of nodes are downgrading to v3 but I want all nodes to be connected to v4 because we want to set the UNSET to avoid nulls converting into tombstones which is only supported with V4

````
Connected to development at 10.1.2.3:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.5 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help. 
cqlsh>

cqlsh 10.1.2.3 --ssl --protocol-version=4
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.1.2.3': DriverException('ProtocolError returned from server while using explicitly set client protocol_version 4',)})  ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across this issue before from another admin where there were gossip "peers" from an older version of Cassandra but no longer part of the cluster.

When performing an upgrade from Cassandra 2.x, new C* 3.x nodes will "negotiate down" to native protocol v3 to prevent issues with clients connecting at a higher protocol version (v4) when some nodes are still running an older version of Cassandra ([CASSANDRA-15193](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15193)).

You can easily verify if this scenario applies to you by going through the `system.log` on problematic nodes and going back to the last startup sequence and look for an entry logged at `INFO` level that looks like:

```
INFO ... Detected peers which do not fully support protocol V4 ...
```

If this is the case, you need to check the `system.peers` table on the node and look for peers (node IP) which has a `release_version` older than Cassandra 3.x:

- If the `peer` is for a node that exists in the cluster, it means it is running an older version of Cassandra and you need to upgrade it.
- If the `peer` is a node that is no longer part of the cluster, remove it with:

```
cqlsh> DELETE FROM system.peers WHERE peer = ?;
```

You might need to delete it multiple times because you're racing against gossip which will constantly repopulate the table. You will also need to repeat this step on nodes which have peers on old versions of Cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Erick. Really appreciate your time explaining above. So our Cassandra cluster is in GKE(Kubernetes), when I check the pod logs (Cassandra node system log) I do see the message you mentioned like below.

`INFO  20:14:09 Detected peers which do not fully support protocol V4. Capping max negotiable version to V3`
The system.peers table is showing all node `release version` is 3.11.5. I do not see any node with older version. 
Your réponse is much appreciated.

Comment: At any point, did you have any nodes/pods running an older version of Cassandra?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Even with the new cluster that we created with same image has the same issue with some nodes.

Comment: Any more ideas is greatly appreciated @Erick Ramirez?

Comment: That sounds like there's an underlying issue with the image you're using. During startup, Cassandra checks all the nodes' `release_version` in the `system.peers` table and if one of them has a version lower than C* 3.0.0 then it will cap the max version to `V3`. You need to workout why a node(s) is advertising itself to be running with an older C* version. You can view the code here -- https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.5/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/ConfiguredLimit.java. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you.Will check and update here.

Comment: Hi Erick Ramirez,

I apologize for the delayed response, wanted to update you that after upgrading Cassandra nodes with new image the issues seems to be fixed. We can close this topic here. If I find more details I will try to update here. I appreciate your responses to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Also the interesting thing that I found on our env is that whenever I see the below error message I could see there are some  IPs which are not part of the cluster. for example in the below log all those 3 IPs are not part of the cluster and they were not showing in sys.peers table.I tried to delete the peers table data files on the node where it is throwing the error and restarted the node, which fixed the issue and populated new peers data files. Is it a standard practice to do? if not is there a way to repair sys.peers table at all without deleting and repopulating new data with restart?

Comment: because of limited chanractes here I am posting the log I mentioned in above comment.

INFO  21:14:26 No version string found for /10.225..9
INFO  21:14:26 No version string found for /10.225.11.7
INFO  21:14:26 No version string found for /10.225.5.164
INFO  21:14:26 Detected peers which do not fully support protocol V4. Capping max negotiable version to V3

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different versions of either Cassandra or cqlsh running? I only recall seeing protocol errors when connecting to Cassandra with a different version of cqlsh than it comes packaged with.

Comment: We have 3.11.5 cassandra image on our GKE cassandra cluster with no cqlsh installed locally, the cqlsh client we installed in a separate namespace to work through dev work where I tried multiple versions of cqlsh, the one comes with 3.11.5 and other latest version. Still the same issue.